# Why am I getting junk characters when I concat a string?

Tags: c

This is my code

```
    char *c[strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 2];
    strcat(c, a);
    strcat(c, "+");
    strcat(c, b);
```

The resulting string c has some junk characters in the beginning, followed by the concatenated string. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You've got two problems, the answers so far each manage to identify just one. (Makes me wish I'd finished typing my answer that hit both!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char c[strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 2];
snprintf(c, sizeof(c), "%s+%s", a, b);
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
char *c = malloc (sizeof (char) * (strlen (a) + strlen (b) + 2));
c[0] = '\0';
strcat(c, a);
strcat(c, "+");
strcat(c, b);
```

The cause of the failure of your routine is because you have done :

```
char *c[strlen(a) + strlen (b) + 2];
```

which declare `c` as an array of pointers, and also not initialized the array with a `'\0'`. It should be like

```
char c[strlen(a) + strlen (b) + 2];
```

You also have to initialize the array with a null string, as `strcat` would find the `'\0'` at the time of concatenation.

Note that there is no problem in execution in error in `char *c[strlen(a) + strlen (b) + 2];` as each location would have 4 bytes in length, so the array can accommodate the characters in it. But this is not correct.

Comment: Correct declaration, but that first strcat will still be problematic.

Comment: This probably isn't downvote worthy, but this does not get to the heart of the problem here. This justs allocates memory on the heap for the string instead of using the stack like s/he wants.

Comment: @Arthur, agreed should do a memset() before starting the strcat; OR could do a snprintf().

Comment: @Suroot, I'd do an `strncpy()` for the first strcat, myself -- but your solutions work too. Perl isn't the only TMTOWTDI language!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have initialize `c[0] = '\0';`, `strcat` will seek until the first `'\0'` before inserting into `c`.

Comment: Correct strcat usage, but the variable declaration will still be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring an array of pointers to char (`char *`).  You need to declare an array of `char`:

```
char c[strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 2];
strcat(c, a);
strcat(c, "+");
strcat(c, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your junk characters are coming from c, you are defining c but it's poiting to some junk value because you haven't initialized them, assign the first character of c to be null, I think that should fix your problem..